# Get User Role Based on ID in bbPress

Tags: wordpress, bbpress

I'm trying to add a column to bbPress 2.x that lists the last person to reply to a topic and adds a specific class to the

if that person is a moderator or keymaster. Unfortunately, I can't find any documentation on the template tags in 2.x. So far, I've been able to get the user ID for the last reply, but I can't seem to find the function that would get the role information for that user based on their ID.

Here's the code that gets the ID:

```
$reply_author_id = bbp_get_reply_author_id( array(  'post_id' => bbp_get_topic_last_active_id() ) );
```

How can I get their bbPress role based on that ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `bbp_get_user_role()` so with your code in mind, this should do the trick. ([Source](https://bbpress.trac.wordpress.org/browser/branches/2.5/includes/users/capabilities.php#L100))

`$role = bbp_get_user_role( $reply_author_id );`